# How long does a typical Windows 7 64bit installation take?

Tags: windows-7, installation, time

On a machine with Intel Core-i5 or i7 and a standard HDD, how long should an installation of Windows 7 64 bit roughly take? I'm after a rough estimate because my installation seems to be running quite slowly (previously, I've installed Win7 32bit on a laptop and it went much quicker but maybe there are differences between 32 and 64 bit editions).

Comment: Mine took less than an hour, but I don't know the exact time because I didn't care to stay in the room the whole time.

Comment: In the end, my installation took about 40 minutes (Core i7, decent SSD, 8GB RAM) so it was probably pretty normal. I was little bit worried at first because the beginning was "weird" - long waiting on screens that didn't provide much feedback of what was going on.

Comment: I also have the long waiting screens. It happened with Vista too. It's only been on computers I have built myself, OEM hardware seems to start off fine. I think it's Windows trying to find drivers.

Comment: Not nearly as long as it takes to load all the updates.

Comment: It usually takes me around an hour to get a booting Windows 7 system with the basic drivers installed.  It then takes at least another day installing updates and service packs.

Comment: It partially depends on how you install windows. If I use a decent USB pendrive then installation is about twice as fast compared to using my DVD.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depends on hardware, remember CPU isn't the only performance factor :)

With decent hardware though, it shouldn't take any longer than 30 - 35 minutes.

Comment: about half an hour seems pretty normal, bit longer maybe :)

Answer (score 1):

I normally allow a full business day for an operating system re-install.  Remember, it's not the system install itself that takes so long; it's all the patches and applications you install *after* the operating system.  Windows 7 isn't that old and so there aren't quite as many patches yet, so you might be able to do it in a little less time.

Comment: Agreed.  I'd also add all of the other applications that need to be installed and updated: Office, AntiVirus, Acrobat, etc..
Then you can't forget restoring settings and data from the machine the user previously used.

Answer (score 0):

Mine on an older laptop (P4 dual core/5200RPM ATA hard drive/2GB ram) took just about an hour.  So it can vary largely based on hardware.

Comment: hard drive is by far the biggest factor, so the 5200rpm drive (are you sure it's not 5400?) really killed you.

Comment: It might even be 4200...

Comment: Whoops, brain fart...  yea, it was a 5400

Answer (score 0):

Less than 15 minutes in a Virtual Machine for me - 4GB ram - normal HDD.

Answer (score -2):

Those times are accurate for a laptop but I have seen desktops take as many 14 to 16 hours with the Vista partition.